# Set Training to False for Validation Data Used in Keras Fit Generator Function

Tags: keras

How do I set `training` to `False` for the `validation_data` used in Keras `fit_generator`? I have `Dropout` layers in my model and I want training to be `True` during training, and `False` during validation and testing.

Answer (score 1):

Keras automatically sets learning_phase to False when doing validation. There is nothing extra that you need to do.

Dropout nodes automatically check whether they are in training mode.

https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/core.py#L126

If you want to verify that Keras automatically changes the learning mode flag you can execute the code bellow. It adds a Lambda layer that adds a print tensor to the graph that outputs a different message in each case.

```
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K

def inspect(x):
  xp = K.in_train_phase(K.print_tensor(x, message='train x:'),
                        K.print_tensor(x, message='test x:'))
  return xp

def make_model():
  inp = Input(shape=(4,))
  h1 = Dense(2)(inp)
  h1p = Lambda(inspect)(h1)
  out = Dense(1)(h1p)
  model = Model(inp, out)
  model.compile('adam', 'mse')
  return model

model = make_model()
model.summary()


import numpy as np

X_train = np.random.rand(1, 4)
Y_train = np.random.rand(1, 1)
X_test = np.random.rand(1, 4)
Y_test = np.random.rand(1, 1)

model.fit(X_train, Y_train, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test))
```

Comment: Then why when I print `K.learning_phase()` from within my data generator function does it print `0` both when running on training data and validation data?

Comment: I believe that the data generator doesn't run from the TensorFlow graph; at least in TensorFlow < 2.0 it runs as a python function independently and then the graph is called. K.learning_phase would be set while executing the graph. If you want to use K.learning_phase you need to do so within a function that executes during the graph operations.

Comment: Even still, if it is changing at the graph, should I not be able to see that change if I print from the generator function? Where could I place a print to see when the change is occuring?

Comment: If I add a print above the return statement in the call function in the core module (the source you posted), I would see it there, yes?

Comment: @A.Hendry the generator function is not be able (AFAIK) to see what happens inside the graph. If you want to see what happens inside the graph you need to an operation on tensors in the graph.

Comment: See this blog article by Francois Chollet (https://blog.keras.io/keras-as-a-simplified-interface-to-tensorflow-tutorial.html). It's from 2016, but still confirms my doubt.

Comment: @A.Hendry See the code sample in the answer. It proves that Keras automatically sets the learning_phase flag appropriately as I mentioned. The Dropout layer reads that flag. Printing any tensor operation in the generator is not an effective way to determine what is going on.

Comment: Then what is an effective way to determine what is going on? I would like to validate that Keras is actually doing what it is saying. There is a lot of misinformation out on the web, and I need to directly validate that Keras is doing this. How do the developers determine it is working without a print?

Comment: @A.Hendry The code snippet above uses K.in_train_phase in the same way the line of code that I quoted above used by the ```Dropout``` layer. It is an effective way to ensure that ```in_train_phase``` works as expected. i.e. set in training and not set for validation and test. The current versions of Keras do automatically set the "feed_dict" used by tensorflow.

Answer (score -2):

I added an `is_training` argument to my data generator function. If it's `True`, I set the Keras learning phase to 1, else to 0 (see docs at keras.io/backend/):

```
if is_training:
    K.set_learning_phase( 1 )
else:
    K.set_learning_phase( 0 )
```

So, for my training data generator, I use `is_training = True`, and for my validation data generator, I use `is_training = False`.

Comment: Whoever downvoted, see this blog article by Francois Chollet (blog.keras.io/…). It's from 2016, but still confirms my doubt.